# How do I override a hover function with a click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a left side fixed navigation menu that is inherently condensed. When it's hovered, it expands to full width.

I've decided to place a toggle switch within the navigation so a user can choose to keep the navigation menu at full width without having to hover over the fixed navigation.

In a nutshell, I want the navigation menu to expand to full width when it's hovered, but I want it to remain expanded at full width when the toggle switch is clicked.

The problem is my jQuery setup, in which the navigation menu still continues to expand and condense on hover, but the toggle switch doesn't keep the navigation menu expanded when it's clicked.

```js
// Navigation Animation
$('.left').hover(function() {
  $('.left').addClass('show');
}, function() {
  $('.left').removeClass('show');
});

$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.left').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
}

.left.show {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
  </div>
</div class="right">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use another class for click events?

Comment: So simple! Thanks, @nitrex! I guess it didn't occur to me because I try to code so efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hover with CSS to avoid this issue:

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.left').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.left:hover,
.left.show {
  width: 300px;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="toggle">Click me</div>
```